# How to make weird fill in on brushstroke go away?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, brush

Ok, I dont know why this happens but need a solution other than switching to basic brush. Sometimes when I draw with this brush (something other than basic): (3pt round):

[image]

I have this weird fill in that changes when you rotate the path:

[image]

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: What's "weird" about it?  Get rid of what?  What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: Have the same varying thickness but not fill in parts with black

Comment: Sorry, but we can only make guesses here. We do not know what is the unwanted oart - is it cyan, black or what? If it's the dark red, try at firsr remove the fill color. Illustrator tries to fill also open shapes assuming a straight closing segment.

Comment: Disable GPU rendering?

Comment: Are you using a tablet? Possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65832/wacom-tablet-illustrator-brush-tool